# modprobe: Module ext4 not found. WARNING: no dependencies for kernel module 'ext4' found

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

I rebooted a compiled kernel 3.1.0, and those are the errors that I am getting:

```
linux-dopx:/usr/src/linux-3.1.0-1.2 # make install
sh /usr/src/linux-3.1.0-1.2/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.1.0 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
                System.map "/boot"

Kernel image:   /boot/vmlinuz-3.1.0
Initrd image:   /boot/initrd-3.1.0
Root device:    /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part2 (/dev/sda2) (mounted on / as ext4)
Resume device:  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part1 (/dev/sda1)
find: `/lib/modules/3.1.0/kernel/drivers/ata': No such file or directory
modprobe: Module ata_generic not found.
WARNING: no dependencies for kernel module 'ata_generic' found.
modprobe: Module ext4 not found.
WARNING: no dependencies for kernel module 'ext4' found.
Features:       block usb resume.userspace resume.kernel
Bootsplash:     openSUSE (1280x1024)
41713 blocks
```

Rebooting says: `Could not load /lib/modules/3.1.0/modules.dep`

### EDIT1:

Here's what I did:

```
linux-dopx:/usr/src/linux-3.1.0-1.2 # make bzImage
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#1)
linux-dopx:/usr/src/linux-3.1.0-1.2 # make modules
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 3 modules
linux-dopx:/usr/src/linux-3.1.0-1.2 # make modules install
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 3 modules
sh /usr/src/linux-3.1.0-1.2/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.1.0 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
                System.map "/boot"

Kernel image:   /boot/vmlinuz-3.1.0
Initrd image:   /boot/initrd-3.1.0
Root device:    /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part2 (/dev/sda2) (mounted on / as ext4)
Resume device:  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part1 (/dev/sda1)
find: `/lib/modules/3.1.0/kernel/drivers/ata': No such file or directory
modprobe: Module ata_generic not found.
WARNING: no dependencies for kernel module 'ata_generic' found.
modprobe: Module ext4 not found.
WARNING: no dependencies for kernel module 'ext4' found.
Features:       block usb resume.userspace resume.kernel
Bootsplash:     openSUSE (1280x1024)
41713 blocks
linux-dopx:/usr/src/linux-3.1.0-1.2 # make install
sh /usr/src/linux-3.1.0-1.2/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.1.0 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
                System.map "/boot"

Kernel image:   /boot/vmlinuz-3.1.0
Initrd image:   /boot/initrd-3.1.0
Root device:    /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part2 (/dev/sda2) (mounted on / as ext4)
Resume device:  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part1 (/dev/sda1)
find: `/lib/modules/3.1.0/kernel/drivers/ata': No such file or directory
modprobe: Module ata_generic not found.
WARNING: no dependencies for kernel module 'ata_generic' found.
modprobe: Module ext4 not found.
WARNING: no dependencies for kernel module 'ext4' found.
Features:       block usb resume.userspace resume.kernel
Bootsplash:     openSUSE (1280x1024)
41713 blocks
```

### EDIT2:

```
linux-dopx:/usr/src/linux-3.1.0-1.2 # make modules_install install
  INSTALL arch/x86/kernel/test_nx.ko
  INSTALL drivers/scsi/scsi_wait_scan.ko
  INSTALL net/netfilter/xt_mark.ko
  DEPMOD  3.1.0
sh /usr/src/linux-3.1.0-1.2/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.1.0 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
                System.map "/boot"

Kernel image:   /boot/vmlinuz-3.1.0
Initrd image:   /boot/initrd-3.1.0
Root device:    /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part2 (/dev/sda2) (mounted on / as ext4)
Resume device:  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part1 (/dev/sda1)
find: `/lib/modules/3.1.0/kernel/drivers/ata': No such file or directory
modprobe: Module ata_generic not found.
WARNING: no dependencies for kernel module 'ata_generic' found.
modprobe: Module ext4 not found.
WARNING: no dependencies for kernel module 'ext4' found.
Features:       block usb resume.userspace resume.kernel
Bootsplash:     openSUSE (1280x1024)
41713 blocks
```

### EDIT 3:

This message is still getting shown after make install: `/lib/modules/2.6.35.13/kernel/drivers/ata': No such file or directory`

I set to '[*]' the "**Generic ATA support**" under "**Serial ATA and Parallel ATA driver**", but that's of no avail.
The kernel version is different this time, but the problem is same.

### EDIT 4:

```
linux-dopx:~ # lspci -vvv
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 10)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM Motherboard
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0b <?>
        Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM Motherboard
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
        Region 0: Memory at fea80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
        Region 1: I/O ports at dc00 [size=8]
        Region 2: Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Region 3: Memory at fe900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: fee0100c  Data: 4149
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Kernel driver in use: i915

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
            Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83a1
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 20
        Region 0: Memory at fea78000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000fee0100c  Data: 4159
        Capabilities: [70] Express (v1) Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ExtTag- RBE- FLReset-
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed unknown, Width x0, ASPM unknown, Latency L0 <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed unknown, Width x0, TrErr- Train- SlotClk- DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
                VC1:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable- ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=00
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Capabilities: [130 v1] Root Complex Link
                Desc:   PortNumber=0f ComponentID=00 EltType=Config
                Link0:  Desc:   TargetPort=00 TargetComponent=00 AssocRCRB- LinkType=MemMapped LinkValid+
                        Addr:   00000000fed1c000
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
        Memory behind bridge: 7f900000-7fafffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 000000007fb00000-000000007fcfffff
        Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
        Capabilities: [40] Express (v1) Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
                        ExtTag- RBE- FLReset-
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <1us, L1 <4us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x0, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                SltCap: AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug+ Surprise+
                        Slot #4, PowerLimit 25.000W; Interlock- NoCompl-
                SltCtl: Enable: AttnBtn- PwrFlt- MRL- PresDet- CmdCplt- HPIrq- LinkChg-
                        Control: AttnInd Unknown, PwrInd Unknown, Power- Interlock-
                SltSta: Status: AttnBtn- PowerFlt- MRL- CmdCplt- PresDet- Interlock-
                        Changed: MRL- PresDet- LinkState-
                RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna- CRSVisible-
                RootCap: CRSVisible-
                RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: fee0100c  Data: 4129
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8179
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
                VC1:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable- ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=00
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Capabilities: [180 v1] Root Complex Link
                Desc:   PortNumber=01 ComponentID=00 EltType=Config
                Link0:  Desc:   TargetPort=00 TargetComponent=00 AssocRCRB- LinkType=MemMapped LinkValid+
                        Addr:   00000000fed1c001
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
        Memory behind bridge: feb00000-febfffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 000000007f700000-000000007f8fffff
        Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
        Capabilities: [40] Express (v1) Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
                        ExtTag- RBE- FLReset-
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #2, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <1us, L1 <4us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                SltCap: AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug+ Surprise+
                        Slot #0, PowerLimit 0.000W; Interlock- NoCompl-
                SltCtl: Enable: AttnBtn- PwrFlt- MRL- PresDet- CmdCplt- HPIrq- LinkChg-
                        Control: AttnInd Unknown, PwrInd Unknown, Power- Interlock-
                SltSta: Status: AttnBtn- PowerFlt- MRL- CmdCplt- PresDet+ Interlock-
                        Changed: MRL- PresDet+ LinkState+
                RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna- CRSVisible-
                RootCap: CRSVisible-
                RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: fee0100c  Data: 4141
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8179
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
                VC1:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable- ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=00
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Capabilities: [180 v1] Root Complex Link
                Desc:   PortNumber=02 ComponentID=00 EltType=Config
                Link0:  Desc:   TargetPort=00 TargetComponent=00 AssocRCRB- LinkType=MemMapped LinkValid+
                        Addr:   00000000fed1c001
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM,P5LD2-VM Mainboard
        Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 5
        Region 4: I/O ports at d400 [size=32]
        Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM,P5LD2-VM Mainboard
        Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 7
        Region 4: I/O ports at d480 [size=32]
        Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM,P5LD2-VM Mainboard
        Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 3
        Region 4: I/O ports at d800 [size=32]
        Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM,P5LD2-VM Mainboard
        Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin D routed to IRQ 10
        Region 4: I/O ports at d880 [size=32]
        Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM,P5LD2-VM Mainboard
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 5
        Region 0: Memory at fea77c00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
        Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
        Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=32
        I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-00000fff
        Memory behind bridge: fff00000-000fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fff00000-00000000000fffff
        Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
        Capabilities: [50] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8179

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM Motherboard
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM Motherboard
        Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx+
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 3
        Region 0: I/O ports at 01f0 [size=8]
        Region 1: I/O ports at 03f4 [size=1]
        Region 2: I/O ports at 0170 [size=8]
        Region 3: I/O ports at 0374 [size=1]
        Region 4: I/O ports at ffa0 [size=16]
        Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA IDE Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM Motherboard
        Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 7
        Region 0: I/O ports at d080 [size=8]
        Region 1: I/O ports at d000 [size=4]
        Region 2: I/O ports at cc00 [size=8]
        Region 3: I/O ports at c880 [size=4]
        Region 4: I/O ports at c800 [size=16]
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5KPL-VM Motherboard
        Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 7
            Region 4: I/O ports at 0400 [size=32]
        Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8136
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
        Region 0: I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
        Region 2: Memory at febff000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Expansion ROM at febc0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0-,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [48] Vital Product Data
                Unknown small resource type 05, will not decode more.
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000fee0100c  Data: 4151
        Capabilities: [60] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <128ns, L1 unlimited
                        ExtTag+ AttnBtn+ AttnInd+ PwrInd+ RBE- FLReset-
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr+ FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s, Latency L0 unlimited, L1 unlimited
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk- DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        Capabilities: [84] Vendor Specific Information: Len=4c <?>
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq+ ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 14, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
        Capabilities: [12c v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Capabilities: [148 v1] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-36-4c-e0-00
        Capabilities: [154 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
        Kernel driver in use: r8169

linux-dopx:~ #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable module ata_generic and module ext4 in menuconfig. The option are:

1. CONFIG_ATA_GENERIC=y: http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/ATA_GENERIC.html
2. CONFIG_EXT4_FS=y: http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/EXT4_FS.html

Comment: David, please see the edit in the question. The ext4 option worked well. But, I am not able to figure what to do for this ATA thing.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Can you post your lspci -vvv? I don't have ATA Generic enabled but PATA module? You must enable the PATA module for your controller?

Comment: There are lots of PATA module types. I couldn't find any generic one. Have added the lspci output. Please take a look.

Comment: The have deleted my edit of the answers. I don't understand why there has to be a peer review if I edit my answer? About your problem: Did you read what I posted? Did you run make modules_install after make? make install is to install the kernel image only?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you did not build (or, install) the kernel modules. That should be a "make modules_install" step, after the main compile. Check out http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/how-to-compile-and-install-linux-kernel-3-0-in-ubuntu-11-04-10-10-and-10-04/ for instance, for ubuntu-like platforms, or state your distro and what commands did you run to compile.

Comment: see edit, on the original question

Comment: according to what I've read, the last make command should be: "make modules_install install"

Comment: see edit, on the original question, again

Comment: @AnishaKaul: The command is make modules_install. Did you tried a depmod -a? Did you enable the module?

Comment: @David I did `# make modules_install`, it resulted in `INSTALL arch/x86/kernel/test_nx.ko 
  INSTALL drivers/scsi/scsi_wait_scan.ko
  INSTALL net/netfilter/xt_mark.ko
  DEPMOD  3.1.0` depmod -a didn't say anything. Doing the make install again results in the same error. BTW, what did you mean by `Did you enable the module` How to enable the module?

Comment: Distro is OpenSuse 11.3.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: You must enable module ata_generic and module ext4 in menuconfig: CONFIG_ATA=y.

Comment: David I searched for "ata_generic" and got to "ata sff support" and option already has a *(star) in []. I couldn't find any place for "CONFIG_ATA=y". and I found "ext4" under file systems option, and placed a *(star) [] besides it. This time I rebooted and was able to login. But the warning of "ata_generic" still persists at boot time! How to solve that?

Comment: The option is CONFIG_ATA_GENERIC: http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/ATA_GENERIC.html

Comment: @David I'll try that. Also, if ou put all that as an asnwer, I'll select it.